# Как правильно написать эффект параллакса

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

Пытаюсь сделать эффект паралакса на сайте http://getscalc.beget.tech/
но беда в том, что фоновые картинки на нижних блоках уезжают вверх.

Вот код:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $objWindow = $(window);
  $('.para').each(function() {
    var $bgObj = $(this);
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var yPos = -($objWindow.scrollTop() / 10);

      var coords = '100% ' + yPos + 'px';
      // Animate the background 
      $bgObj.css({
        backgroundPosition: coords
      });

    });

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно узнать насколько смещен экран относительно текущего блока, а не всего документа в целом. Поэтому из позиции скрола отнимите позицию секции:

```
var yPos = -(($objWindow.scrollTop()-$bgObj.offset().top) / 10);
```